# How to reset a component's data

Tags: vue.js

Under certain conditions I want to reinitialize a component's data to what it started with. As a start, instead of having the properties specified within the data(), I call a function which returns a data object, thus:

```
data() {
 return this.initialData();
},
```

How can I call this again in, say, $watch? Can I actually directly write to the data object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API documentation on `data`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> After the instance is created, the original data object can be accessed as vm.$data.

So it should be as simple as `Object.assign(this.$data, this.initialData());`

Comment: It can be accessed but can it be replaced?

Comment: Apparently not, or at least it's not a good idea; " [Vue warn]: Avoid replacing instance root $data. Use nested data properties instead."

Comment: Good remark. You could always do `Object.assign(this.$data, this.initialData())` to set properties one by one.

Comment: And yes, that works! Thanks!